# Optimizing travel double for loop using swift

Tags: arrays, swift, optimization, traversal

I used minimum edit distance algorithm to find the bundle of the most similar strings in an array.

So, I have to travel double `for` loop to compare all element.

If the data is large enough, this algorithm is Inefficient.

Is there a way to optimize?

```swift
let data = [
  "10000", // count
  "asdfqwerty", "asdfzxcvgh", "asdfpoiuyt",
  ...
]

for i in 1..<data.count {
  let string = data[i]
  for j in (i + 1)..<data.count {
    let newMin = string.minimumEditDistance(other: data[j])

    if min >= newMin {
      // some logic
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
extension String {
  public func minimumEditDistance(other: String, `default`: Int = 10) -> Int {
    let m = self.count
    let n = other.count

    if m == 0 || n == 0 {
      return `default`
    }

    var matrix = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: n + 1), count: m + 1)

    // initialize matrix
    for index in 1...m {
      // the distance of any first string to an empty second string
      matrix[index][0] = index
    }

    for index in 1...n {
      // the distance of any second string to an empty first string
      matrix[0][index] = index
    }

    // compute Levenshtein distance
    for (i, selfChar) in self.enumerated() {
      for (j, otherChar) in other.enumerated() {
        if otherChar == selfChar {
          // substitution of equal symbols with cost 0
          matrix[i + 1][j + 1] = matrix[i][j]
        } else {
          // minimum of the cost of insertion, deletion, or substitution
          // added to the already computed costs in the corresponding cells
          matrix[i + 1][j + 1] = Swift.min(matrix[i][j] + 1, matrix[i + 1][j] + 1, matrix[i][j + 1] + 1)
        }
      }
    }
    return matrix[m][n]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's problematic? Which line is causing it?

Comment: Please, clarify the task: are you comparing elements in the same array, or you comparing each element of one dataset with each element of another dataset?

Comment: @fewlinesofcode yes, it's same array.

Comment: @koen this code no have problems as functionally. but this algorithm is O(n^2), I want to optimize

Comment: You can achieve desired behaviour by sorting your array using your `minimumEditDistance` as a sorting function and then taking first or last element (depends on how you define sorting) and what you need - min or max. It will likely run in O(N*log(N)) time. Which is already better than exponential

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do. This looks like an NP problem. If there is an optimization, it will come only from the definition of `minimumEditDistance`. Maybe sorting the array first would help to improve the algorithm. You will have to show us how `minimumEditDistance` is defined.

Comment: @fewlinesofcode Only if the distance is transitive. That's not implied here. If the distance is some kind of string similarity, then sorting won't be possible.

Comment: @Sulthan editing distance is transitive.

Comment: @Sulthan added ```minimumEditDistance```

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Minimum%20Edit%20Distance ?

Comment: @koen yes I used it.

Comment: @fewlinesofcode Not all editing distances are transitive, Jaro–Winkler is not, for example. Levenshtein is therefore you comment would be a good answer.

Comment: @Sulthan, JaroWinkler is not a metric, as far as I remember. I agree with you. Yet for Levenstain sorting is acceptable ghetto-solution. Thanks

Comment: I changed my question for detail. I couldn't understand your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve desired behaviour by sorting your array using your `minimumEditDistance` as a sorting function and then taking first or last element (depends on how you define sorting) and what you need - min or max. It will likely run in `O(N*log(N))` time. Which is already better than exponential.

As @Sultan mentioned, it will work not for all distances, as transitivity is applicable only to Metrics (functions that define a distance between each element of the set). You're using Levenstain distance as an editing distance algorithm, which is indeed a metric. The solution I mentioned should help to optimise in some circumstances.

Comment: I changed my question for detail. I couldn't understand your answers. Pls, check my question again.

Comment: To be honest, you don't actually need sorting, you just need the `min(by:)` function. `min` is much easier than sorting, it can be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Sulthan, actually, it’s true

Comment: The problematic part is that you are looking for the min distance of two elements, therefore you still need to generate all pairs and find the pair with the minimum distance. That still comes as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Sulthan, so I did some research, and in planar case there is better algorithm to find minimum distance between points. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/ By opportunity will try to apply it to editing distance. The problem is how to define a function that makes correspondence between string and particular point on the plane and keeps distances correct...